# Script de bash en el que ingreses valor numerico y se ejecute con ese valor

Tags: bash, script

Tengo este pequeño script en Bash para subir o bajar el brillo de mi laptop:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness <<< 10
```

En el cual "10" es el valor numérico a cambiar.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hacer para que abra el script desde una terminal, me pida un numero, y luego se ejecute ese numero?

Answer (score 2):

No se preocupen, ya lo resolví. Aca dejo la respuesta por si alguien lo necesita.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo Por favor, ingresa el brillo que deseas en tu pantalla 
read varbright
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness <<< $varbright
```

Comment: Marca esta respuesta como válida, para que sepamos que es la respuesta final

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar los parámetros del sistema, leerlos y ejecutar con esos valores.

Cuando ejecutas algo como:

Programa.sh 10

Dentro de programa.sh puedes leer el parametro 10 con $1, y podrías escribir algo como:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness <<< $1
```

$0 sería el nombre del archivo, en este ejemplo sería programa1.sh

$1 sería el primer parametro, aquí valdría 10

Y así sucesivamente...